# Retriving by date or by customer name or customer name with specific date

Tags: mysql

I built small project of Mysql/Php.  I am trying to select purchase report
.customer name, or 
.from date to date or 
.customer name with specific date.

I am using this code:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM client
WHERE 
(`customer_name` = '$_REQUEST[q2]' AND (`date` BETWEEN '$_REQUEST[q]' AND '$_REQUEST[q1]') )
OR (`customer_name` = '$_REQUEST[q2]')
OR (`date` BETWEEN '$_REQUEST[q]' AND '$_REQUEST[q1]')
";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Anyone can help

Thanks

Comment: What's not working right now? Side note: always escape `$_REQUEST` parameters or use [statement binding](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to prevent code injection.

Comment: @Afrik also use mysqli instead of mysql. This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0